# Multiple erc20 tokens approval in one transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, transactions, erc-20

Is it possible to set approval for multiple different erc20 tokens in one transaction? As for now I have this function but it does not seem to work when tested.

```
function batchApprove(address tokenAddress, address[] memory spenders, uint256[] memory amounts) external {
    require(spenders.length == amounts.length, "Mismatched input lengths");

    IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < spenders.length; i++) {
        require(token.approve(spenders[i], amounts[i]), "Approval failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: UserA (address 0x1111...) -> `batchApprove` on your Contract (e.g. address 0x2222... -> Token . You want to approve `spender` to use UserA's Token or Contract's Token

Comment: I want to approve spender (my contract) to use UserA's Tokens. But after some heavy testing it seems to be impossible to make in one transaction.

Comment: And as i managed to understand my function correctly - with this function i am allowing user to use tokens that already are within my contract. That is not what i intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the approve function via a contract then the spender will be allowed to spend the contract's token and not the `msg.sender`'s tokens. The reason is while calling the approve function, the contract becomes the `msg.sender` and it approves its own tokens to spender.

If the goal is to approve the tokens held by an EOA, you would need to call the approve function and no, this won't be possible in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

As said previously you are trying to **call approve from your contract**.

The function approve will approve for the caller (msg.sender) of the function as seen in OpenZeppelin's implementation of ERC20:

[image]

When a **function calls an other function** (inside of itself) **it** (the contract) **becomes the caller**.

In your function

```
for (uint256 i = 0; i < spenders.length; i++) {
    require(token.approve(spenders[i], amounts[i]), "Approval failed");
}
```

you are basically giving the spenders of your array the approvals to spend the **tokens owned by the contract**.

What you want to do is not possible.
To give an address some allowance the **owner of the funds MUST be the one calling** the approve function.
Otherwise there would be here a **serious security issue** as you could choose at will to give approval for other addresses.